# setting footer Value from server in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

The column footer calculation  on our project is a complex one hence we need to do bring the column footer values from server.

I am using expandable_grid.
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid
The data structure it uses does not have custom column footer values.
How do I format my footer values in the json.

```
jsonData = [
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "guid": "de3db502-0a33-4e47-a0bb-35b6235503ca",
        "address": {
            "street": 317,
            "city": "Blairstown",
            "state": "Maine",
            "zip": 390
        },
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Mangesh"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "guid": "de3db502-0a33-4e47-a0bb-35b6235503cb",
        "address": {
            "street": 318,
            "city": "Blairstown",
            "state": "Maine",
            "zip": 390
        },
        "friends": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": "ABCD"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Where do I put my footer data for outer and inner(friends) grid.
I created Aggregation Function but it seems the data format I am passing is not correct.

Can you guide me.

Comment: Have you seen the [footerTemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874761/how-to-get-angular-ui-grid-footertemplate-to-work)?

Comment: Thanks @fracz I missed that it was column footer and not grid footer.Every column values needs to change when the data is retrieved from server.

Comment: You can simulate column footers in the grid footer - just adjust the styles properly.

Comment: oh nice I can try that but for footer data do I need to get footer data in the same json or I will have to get it in other call.